# load() jquery shows results twice Jquery

Tags: jquery, function

I have a function, where

```
 //s > selector which define the number of Sql results given by results.php?selector=s

jQuery.fn.ShowResults = function(s){

 $("#results").load("results.php?selector="+s);
 }

  $("#results").ShowResults(1);

 $("#show1").on("click", function(e){  $("#results").ShowResults(1);});
 $("#show2").on("click", function(e){  $("#results").ShowResults(2);});
 $("#show3").on("click", function(e){  $("#results").ShowResults(3);});
```

I have by default `selector=1`;

```
 <a id=show1>Show 1</a>
 <a id=show2>Show 2</a>
 <a id=show3>Show 3</a>

 <ul id=results></ul>
```

The Sql is

```
 $s=$_GET['selector'];
 SELECT * WHERE condition AND selector='$s'
```

PHP

```
 $results=mysql_query("SELECT * WHERE condition AND selector='$s'");

 while($res=mysql_fetch_array($results)){

 $data=$res['names'];
 echo "<li>$data</li>";
 }
```

the problem is that sometimes, it looks like the function is called twice, and shows the same results repeated like this

```
  <ul id=results>
      <li>AAA</li>
      <li>BBB</li>
      <li>CCC</li>
      <li>AAA</li>
      <li>BBB</li>
      <li>CCC</li>
  </ul>
```

I have tried to use `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropagation();` with no solution

The question is how do I stop this function behaviour? It looks like that anytime I click the anchors, I call twice the same function and conflicts with the set by default

Comment: What is returned from `php`?

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql_fetch_array($results)` is returning result in both associative indices as well as numbered indices that is why it is shown twice.
use `mysql_fetch_row($results)` instead.

> The type of returned array depends on how result_type is defined. By using MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get an array with both associative and number indices. Using MYSQL_ASSOC, you only get associative indices (as mysql_fetch_assoc() works), using MYSQL_NUM, you only get number indices (as mysql_fetch_row() works).

Comment: But it only happens 1 in 50. If using fetxh

Comment: echo the `$result` to see whether it returns mixed, associative or numbered array. This way you can see when it happens.

Comment: These might help in narrowing down the reason.
[fetch asoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)  ,
[fetch row](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)

Comment: my friend I am testing with `mysql_fetch_row` and the problem still exist :/, I think that the `Jquery `

Comment: I think the `Jquery` could be the problem